# Pointer address standards-compliant conversion

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, standards-compliance

I need to find the most standards-compliant way to obtain the address of a pointer and store its bytes separately (for instance, to transmit them serially).

I have two versions below, the first one which contains, I believe, undefined behavior, and the second one, which should contain only defined behavior according to C99. But my tool tells me I have undefined behavior on the second one as well. Could someone please confirm it, and indicate a solution with neither undefined behavior, nor implementation-defined behavior, if possible?

**Edit**: I changed the type from `int` to `unsigned long` to aid in finding a non-implementation-dependent solution. I also removed the "16-bit wide pointer".

```
unsigned long a[2];
unsigned char b0, b1, b2, b3;

int main1() {
  unsigned long l = (unsigned long) &(a[0]);
  b0 = (l >> 24) & 0xFF;
  b1 = (l >> 16) & 0xFF;
  b2 = (l >> 8) & 0xFF;
  b3 = l & 0xFF;
  return 0;
}


typedef union { unsigned long* p; char c[sizeof(unsigned long *)]; } u;

int main2() {
  u x;
  x.p = a;
  b0 = x.c[3];
  b1 = x.c[2];
  b2 = x.c[1];
  b3 = x.c[0];
  return 0;
}
```

**Edit 2**: added reference to a part of the C99 standard concerning these programs:

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

Does it mean it is not possible to read the address of array `a` without relying on some implementation-defined behavior? Or is there a way to circumvent it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to transmit addresses? They won't be valid on another host or another address space anyway.

Comment: I'm not aware of any implementation of C that has 16-bit pointers, but assuming you're right about that (some small embedded system or something?) there's nothing wrong with main1(). You're apparently using a union or something for main2(), but you're not showing us that code so we can't help you.

Comment: `int i = (int) &(a[0]);`  con be problematic because `sizeof(int) != sizeof(void*)` on some systems

Comment: As I said, I'm assuming he's right about 16-bit pointers (which is not the case on any system I know of). The only possible "undefined behavior" is throwing away all but the low 16 bits of pointer.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: The OP does not use `void *`. It is using `int *`.

Comment: @alk `sizeof(void *)` always **=** `sizeof(int *)`

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker sorry, you're right, I forgot to add the typedef for the union. I also replace b0 and b1 with `unsigned` chars.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I doubt this is true. As it might appael to many platforms, all that is guaranteed by the standard (from my knowlegde) is `sizeof(void*)==sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Motorola 6811 pointers are 16 bit. Also, 8086 'near' pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pointers, it is better to use type `unsigned long` (or `unsigned long long`). Unless there is `uintptr_t` data type.
Why `unsigned`? Because shift operations are common only for unsigned integers. For signed ones, it is platform-dependent.

So it you want to transfer the address (for whatever reason, as address is usually process-local), you can do like the following:

```
/**
 * @param ptr Pointer to serialize
 * @param buf Destination buffer
 * @param be  If 0 - little endian, 1 - big endian encoding
 */
void ptr2buf(const void *ptr, void *buf, int be)
{
    uintptr_t u = (uintptr_t)ptr;
    unsigned char *d = buf;

    if (be)
    {
        /* big endian */
        d += sizeof(t) - 1;

        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(t); ++i)
        {
            *d-- = u & 0xFF;
            u >>= 8;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* little endian */

        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(t); ++i)
        {
            *d++ = u & 0xFF;
            u >>= 8;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so if my tool tells me all three programs (both my versions and yours) have an undefined behavior, it's my tool that accepts only a subset of C? Does line `*d-- = u & 0xFF` contains undefined behavior? Or just implementation-defined behavior? If so, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: This code is correct for all machines. No, the line you point out is 100% correct and compliant. If you have some tool telling you otherwise, it's worthless.

Comment: Just to clarify what I could grasp from the standard: `u & 0xFF` contains a pointer type (`u`) and a bitwise AND operator. The pointer type is then converted into an integer type, which according to item 6.3.2.3.6 in the C99 standard, "the result is implementation-defined", and then the bitwise operation is performed on the result of the conversion.
In other words, I believe there is no way to perform this conversion without relying on at least some implementation-defined behavior, which means your solution (and probably mine) are both standards-compliant.

Comment: @dhekir `u` is not a pointer type. it's an integer type with sufficient size to hold pointer value.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk ok, so the implementation-defined conversion from pointer to integer happens at `uintptr_t u = (uintptr_t)ptr`.

Comment: @dhekir Correct. And if it is using `uintptr_t` type, it is portable as long as target platform supports this type.